# maximum number of uprobe /kprobe that can be attached using libbpf

Tags: kprobe, libbpf, uprobe

Is there a limit on how many uprobes /kprobes that can be attached at the same time? Or is there a kernel config that I can change?

Need limits values ,so that I can decide about bpf user space doe data structure size.

Using latest libbf routine like with pattern
bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi
bpf_program__attach_kprobe_multi